# Upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 now Simple Desktop Display Manager (SDDM) won't start

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, do-release-upgrade, sddm

After upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 via `do-release-upgrade` I can now only boot into TTY mode. The boot log shows:

`[FAILED] Failed to start Simple Desktop Display Manager.
See 'systemctl status sddm.service' for details.`

Looking following the suggestion for more details I see:

```
sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-05-24 18:35:01 CEST; 4min 58s ago
     Docs: man:sddm(1)
           man:sddm.conf(5)
  Process: 1801 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/bin/sddm" ] (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 18:35:00 miked-Ubuntu systemd[1]: sddm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 24 18:35:01 miked-Ubuntu systemd[1]: sddm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 24 18:35:01 miked-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Simple Desktop Display Manager.
May 24 18:35:01 miked-Ubuntu systemd[1]: sddm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 24 18:35:01 miked-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple Desktop Display Manager.
```

Once I am in TTY I can start the desktop with: `sudo service lightdm start` and everything appears to be fine.

Any suggestions on how I might resolve this?

Thanks

Update:

I'm running this on a 13" Macbook Pro Retina

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

You will be shown a screen like this:

[image]

Select `lightdm`, press TAB (to select the OK button) and ENTER.

Then run `systemctl disable sddm`

If you don't plan on ever using sddm again uninstall with `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sddm`

Reboot and you should be presented with the lightdm login screen (unless autologin is enabled, then you will go to Desktop).

Comment: fantastic!! thank you very much worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to help out!